# How to make a table fill the entire mobile screen?

Tags: css, html, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a problem making a **table** fill the entire **screen** on a **mobile** app (for now, I'm implementing it on Android only). The page contains only this table, which only takes the size of its content apparently. I tried using `html, body { min-height: 100%}` and putting a `height= 100%` in almost every part of the app but it doesn't work. One detail though : the **BODY**'s 100% is **functional** : the background color is applied to the entire screen; but I need the whole **TABLE** to stretch.

EDIT : I'm working on Eclipse and I use the IBM Worklight Framework.

EDIT2 : The width is working. Filling the height is the problem.

EDIT3 : The viewport setting Owen provided me with is kind of confusing. It doesn't change anything but I have the feeling that I'm not supposed to paste it where I did (the main page .html).
        Code : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: can you post a fiddle with your current code?

Comment: No, sorry. The content of the code is confidential. If it is really necessary, I can repeat its structure with void content but it'll take some time.

Comment: are you creating the table with divs or with <table> ?

Comment: I'm using `<table ...> <tbody> <tr> <td> ... </td> </tr> ... </tbody> </table>`

EDIT : I also have a child table within a table cell.

Comment: if you have this: `html, body {height: 100%}` then do the same to the table: `table {height: 100%}`

Comment: are there any div wraps that could be affecting the height, what is the structure to the document.  i.e  html > body > divwrap > table ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example here: http://cssdesk.com/qEL2L

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
}

table {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background: red;}
```

HTML :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Using the `table { height: 100% }` as suggested by you and Riskbreaker works on the "canvas". I tried selecting various devices on eclipse Worklight and it works. But once I launch it on the device emulator for Android, it just shows up like it used to : not working. Any ideas ?

Comment: have you tried setting the viewport ?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm gonna have to check that later :/

Comment: Where should I set the viewport ? In the common html file or in the android one ? It's not working so far. Sorry to reup the question so late. I had to stop working on that projet for a while.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the table's width and height to 100%? table {width:100%; height:100%}.

Comment: I tried that too. I have no problem for the width, it is perfectly working. The height filling is the problem.